# How do I filter if an optional relationship exists?

Tags: typescript, prisma, prisma2

I have the following schema where `Quiz` is an optional relationship on `User`.

```
model User {
  email String @id @unique
  quiz  Quiz?
}

model Quiz {
  id        String @id @default(uuid())
  user      User   @relation(fields: [userEmail], references: [email], onDelete: Cascade)
  userEmail String
}
```

I want to find all users that do have a quiz relationship.

At first I naively tried the following:

```
const users = await p.user.findMany({
  where: { quiz: true },
})
```

Then I thought I found a solution [in their docs.](https://www.prisma.io/docs/support/help-articles/finding-entities-based-on-relation)

```
const users = await p.user.findMany({
  where: { quiz: { some: {} } },
})
```

But this gives the error:

> Type '{ some: {}; }' is not assignable to type '(Without<QuizRelationFilter, QuizWhereInput> & QuizWhereInput) | (Without<QuizWhereInput, QuizRelationFilter> & QuizRelationFilter) | null | undefined'.
>
> Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'some' does not exist in type '(Without<QuizRelationFilter, QuizWhereInput> & QuizWhereInput) | (Without<QuizWhereInput, QuizRelationFilter> & QuizRelationFilter)'.
>
> 9   where: { quiz: { some: {} } },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you found in the docs works for one-to-many relations. One-to-one relations can be filtered like this:

```
const users = await p.user.findMany({
  where: { quiz: { isNot: null } },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking a solution in cases involving one-to-one relations, where the goal is to filter records by a field that is `null`, you can utilize the following Prisma query:

```js
const users = await p.user.findMany({
  where: { quiz: { is: null } },
});
```

This query effectively retrieves records where the 'quiz' field is `null` within the 'user' model, making it a valuable tool for filtering data in such scenarios.